# How to Delete a Data Extension Folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, delete, contactbuilder, folder

Sorry if this sounds like a silly question, but I can't figure out how to delete or rename a folder I created under Contact Builder -> Data Extensions.

My folder is sitting under the root "Data Extensions" folder, it's empty, and I have admin permissions, but I can't find any element in the GUI that would allow me to delete or rename it.

Comment: It might seem dumb, but did you try to right click on the folder and then select delete?

Comment: Yes, and there's no context-sensitive menu for Salesforce. It's just the standard OS menu with options for copying, pasting, etc.

Comment: What’s the name of that folder? Some names are reserved for system folders, so it you name a folder for example “All subscribers” - you won’t be able to delete it yourself, you will have to contact support.

Comment: It's called "Beta". But anyway, I can't _see_ an option to delete any of the folders I've created, where it's supposed to be?

Comment: On right click. Can you go to Email Studio>Subscribers>Data Extensions and try from there?

Comment: @CodeRage yes, that worked! right-clicking on contact builder doesn't work, but from email studio it does... crappy GUI! If you want to add this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to delete it from Email Studio:

Go to Email Studio > Subscribers > Data Extensions and right click on the folder.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. This is yet another example of Salesforce's crappy GUI: Contact Builder allows us to create folders, but not to delete them. For deleting them, we need to go to Email Studio.

Comment: Yep. Contact builder and email dataextension is another great example where Salesforce did a really bad job. There is so much bs going on when browsing on second pages and switching to a folder which has no second page and so on. Also when you look at warnings and errors that are presented in the developer console you get the a really bad feeling. Sometimes I doubt certain functionality is developed from one of the leading technology firms on earth because it seems so unfinished.