# Moving over 2000+ old Data Extensions to new folder for review/delete

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs, wsproxy

I am trying to move multiple old DEs into a new folder.  And, with my limited experience with SFMC  Objects & WSProxy/SSJS, I dug deep into multiple resources & samples codes like ([Zuzanna  - update DE](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/16/update-multiple-non-sendable-data-extensions-to-be-sendabl)) and @Gortonington([SFMC DE Inventory (Take 2)](https://gortonington.com/sfmc-data-extension-inventory-take-2/)) and a sample code from Gortonington again ([Retrieve DE by folder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311912/automate-data-extension-deletion-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud?noredirect=1&lq=1)). Here is my code (many are sourced from these talented individuals), but I'm getting this error Message:

> Line 22 CustomerKey Returned : [{"CustomerKey":"Einstein_MC_Predictive_Scores"}] {"message":"Error executing update call.","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: Error executing update call.\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_CONTEXT_ERR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nSystem.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

```
<script runat=server>
    Platform.Load("Core","1");
    
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); // Sets the Proxy - DO NOT CHANGE
    
    try { //Will attempt to run the below stuff
      var deArr = getAllDeInfo();  //returns all the DE info from this Business Unit 
      var custkey_Arr = []; //Araarso - move to new folder 
    
      for (var a=0; a<deArr.length;a++) { //Iterate through the array holding each of the objects from the DE info return
        var deData = deArr[a].Results;  //Set the Object for us to pull
    
        for (var e=0; e<deData.length; e++) { //iterate through the Results of that object, setting each value
          var name = deData[e].Name;
    
         //Call the AMPscript function to return DE rowcounts 
        var rowCount = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent('%'+'%=DataExtensionRowCount("' + name + '")=%' + '%');
        var rowCount_format = parseInt(rowCount,10);   //Araarso - format rowCount into Digit since it is string
    
        //Araarso - find current year 
        var dt = new Date();
        var date_end = addDate(dt, -12, 'months');
        
        //Araarso - variable for DE modified Date
        var mod_year = deData[e].ModifiedDate;
    
          if ( (rowCount_format > 1000000) && (mod_year < date_end)) {  //Araarso - condition to include only DE with 2K+ records - Modified/Created 12 Months ago.
            var deObj = {};
            var customerkey_v = deData[e].CustomerKey;
            deObj.CustomerKey = customerkey_v;
            custkey_Arr.push(deObj);
            Write('Line 22 CustomerKey Returned : ' + Stringify(custkey_Arr) + ' ');
     
            //Sets variables pulling in the meta data of the DEs
            var catID = deData[e].CategoryID
              
            //Call the AMPscript function to return DE rowcounts 
            var rowCount = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent('%'+'%=DataExtensionRowCount("' + name + '")=%' + '%');
    
            //Pulls the folder path of the data extension
            var list = [];
              list.push(name);
            var path = function(id) {
                if (id> 0) {
                    var results = Folder.Retrieve({Property:"ID",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:id});
    
                    if(results) {
                      list.unshift(results[0].Name);
                      return path(results[0].ParentFolder.ID);
                    } 
                    else {
                      list = ['error in path retrieve']
                      return list;
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    return id;
                }
            };
            path(catID);
            folderPath = list.join("> ");
    
             if ( folderPath.indexOf("Dir") < 0 ) {   //Araarso -  Condition to EXCLUDE "DESelect folders"                                  
            
                //Araarso - move DE to new folder START
                var catID_v = 200;
    
                //Araarso - Move OLD DE to new folder END
                for(var i=0; i< custkey_Arr.length; i++) {
                    var res = prox.updateItem("DataExtension", {"CustomerKey":custkey_Arr[i], "CategoryID":catID_v});
                    Write(' Line 74 returns : ' + Stringify(res) + "<br>");
                    } 
           } // end restricting Dir folder (Line 69)
          }  //  end  Condition to include only DE with 2K+ records - Modified/Created 12 Months ago. (Line 36)
        }  //    end Results iterative (Line 14)
      }  //      end Array of DE Objects iterative (Line 11)
    
    } //end try (Line 8)
    
    catch(e) { // Instead of tossing an error or exception, this will display the error in an output
    
     Write(Stringify(e)) // Writes the error object to the page
    
    }
    
    function getAllDeInfo() {
      var cols = [
                    "ObjectID"
                    ,"CustomerKey"
                    ,"Name"
                    ,"CategoryID"
                    ,"CreatedDate"
                    ,"ModifiedDate"
                    ,"Client.ID"
                    ,"Description"
                    ,"CategoryID"
                ];
    
      var filter = {
              Property: "CategoryID"
              , SimpleOperator: "notEquals"
              , Value: 200 //do not look new folder
         };
     
    
    
      var reqID = null
      var moreData = true;
      var desc = [];
    
      while(moreData) {
        moreData = false;
        var data = reqID == null ?
        prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter):  
          prox.getNextBatch("DataExtension", reqID);
        if(data != null) {
          moreData = data.HasMoreRows;
          reqID = data.RequestID;
          if(data && data.Results) {
            desc.push(data);
          }
        }
      }
    
      return desc;
    }
    
    //Araarso - function to create date structure 
    function addDate(dt, amount, dateType) {
      switch (dateType) {
        case 'days':
          return dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + amount) && dt;
        case 'weeks':
          return dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + (7 * amount)) && dt;
        case 'months':
          return dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + amount) && dt;
        case 'years':
          return dt.setFullYear( dt.getFullYear() + amount) && dt;
      }
    }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: BTW - When I ran this code in the automation, it runs fine (with no errors) but no DE is moved to the new folder.  However, when I ran it on the Cloud pages, I can see the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question - Finally figured out. Here is my code:

```
    <script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1");

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); // Sets the Proxy - DO NOT CHANGE

try { //Will attempt to run the below stuff
  var deArr = getAllDeInfo();  //returns all the DE info from this Business Unit 
   
  for (var a=0; a<deArr.length;a++) { //Iterate through the array holding each of the objects from the DE info return
    var deData = deArr[a].Results;  //Set the Object for us to pull

    for (var e=0; e< deData.length; e++) { //iterate through the Results of that object, setting each value
         var name = deData[e].Name;
         var catID = deData[e].CategoryID;
         var CustomerKey_v = deData[e].CustomerKey
         Write(' Line 16 returns : ' + Stringify(CustomerKey_v) + "<br>");

     //Call the AMPscript function to return DE rowcounts 
    var rowCount = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent('%'+'%=DataExtensionRowCount("' + name + '")=%' + '%');
    var rowCount_format = parseInt(rowCount,10);   // format rowCount into Digit since it is string

    // find current year 
    var dt = new Date();
    var date_end = addDate(dt, -5, 'months');
  //var date_end = addDate(dt, -12, 'months');
    
    // variable for DE modified Date
    var mod_year = deData[e].ModifiedDate;

      if ( (rowCount_format > 2000) && (mod_year < date_end)) {  //Condition to include only DE with 2K+ records - Modified 12 Months ago.
        //Call the AMPscript function to return DE rowcounts 
        var rowCount = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent('%'+'%=DataExtensionRowCount("' + name + '")=%' + '%');

        //Pulls the folder path of the data extension
        var list = [];
          list.push(name);
        var path = function(id) {
            if (id> 0) {
                var results = Folder.Retrieve({Property:"ID",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:id});

                if(results) {
                  list.unshift(results[0].Name);
                  return path(results[0].ParentFolder.ID);
                } 
                else {
                  list = ['error in path retrieve']
                  return list;
                }
            } 
            else {
                return id;
            }
        };
        path(catID);
        folderPath = list.join("> ");

                                     
         if ( folderPath.indexOf("Dir") < 0 ) { 
            //Folder to move DEs
            var catID_v = 0001;

            //execute 
             var res = prox.updateItem("DataExtension", {"CustomerKey":deData[e].CustomerKey, "CategoryID":catID_v});
             Write(' Line 64 returns : ' + Stringify(res) + "<br>");

       }  
      }  
    }  
  }  

} 

catch(e) { // Instead of tossing an error or exception, this will display the error in an output
           Write(Stringify(e)) // Writes the error object to the page
        }

function getAllDeInfo() {
  var cols = [
             "ObjectID"
                ,"CustomerKey"
                ,"Name"
                ,"CategoryID"
                ,"CreatedDate"
                ,"ModifiedDate"
                ,"Client.ID"
                ,"Description"
            ];

    var filter = {
                  Property: "CategoryID"
                  , SimpleOperator: "notEquals"
                  , Value:0001
                 } 


  var reqID = null
  var moreData = true;
  var desc = [];

  while(moreData) {
    moreData = false;
    var data = reqID == null ?
    prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter): prox.getNextBatch("DataExtension", reqID);
    if(data != null) {
      moreData = data.HasMoreRows;
      reqID = data.RequestID;
      if(data && data.Results) {
        desc.push(data);
      }
    }
  }

  return desc;
}

// function to create date structure 
function addDate(dt, amount, dateType) {
  switch (dateType) {
    case 'days':
      return dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + amount) && dt;
    case 'weeks':
      return dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + (7 * amount)) && dt;
    case 'months':
      return dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + amount) && dt;
    case 'years':
      return dt.setFullYear( dt.getFullYear() + amount) && dt;
  }
}

</script>
```